# How do we perform the following task in crosstab?

Tags: postgresql

Example of ProductSales table.

--Table 
create table productsales
(
  country varchar(20),
  salesman varchar(20),
  amount integer
)

--Insert couple of records into productsales
insert into productsales values('UK','Sam',25000);
...
...

--Query to be perform in "crosstab" in plpgsql, instead of using pivot operator.
select salesman,UK,US,UAE 
from productsales
pivot  -- I know this will not work in plpgsql
(
    sum(amount)
    for country
    IN ([UK],[US],[UAE])
)
AS pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `crosstab` you can use the [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) module that comes with PostgreSQL. You need first to install it (the way of doing that will depend on how you installed PostgreSQL), and then create the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

With that in place, you can simple do your `crosstab` query:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab($$
        /* Your normal query with your own filters (the fields must be always at the same order) */
        SELECT salesman, country, amount
        FROM productsales
        WHERE country IN ('UAE','UK','US')
        /* The ORDER is really important here */
        ORDER BY 1, 2
    $$,
    /* The values that will be crossed, notice they are ordered alphabetically */
    $$VALUES('UAE'),('UK'),('US')$$
) AS
/* Here you tell which columns and types you expect */
productsales(salesman varchar(20), uae integer, uk integer, us integer);
```